# How to include PHP file into Controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sms

I am using SMS API called Text local in PHP. There is a main textlocal.class.php file. This is the code.

```
        include "textlocal.class.php";
        $textlocal = new Textlocal('Username', 'API KEY');
        $numbers = array(MOBILE NUMBER);
        $sender = 'Testing';
        $message = "Your Download image link is available now";

        $textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
```

How to include this in Codigniter controller? Please help me

Comment: `require_once('path_to_file')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codeigniter helper is useful in this case. Best advantage is Helper function will be available wherever needed.

Save below file in Application/Heplers/sendsms_helper.php

```
 /*Start sendsms_helper.php file */

    function sendsms($number, $message_body, $return = '0'){       
        $sender = 'SEDEMO';  // Need to change
        $smsGatewayUrl = 'http://springedge.com';
        $apikey = '62q3z3hs49xxxxxx'; // Change   

        $textmessage = urlencode($textmessage);
        $api_element = '/api/web/send/';
        $api_params = $api_element.'?apikey='.$apikey.'&sender='.$sender.'&to='.$mobileno.
'&message='.$textmessage;    
        $smsgatewaydata = $smsGatewayUrl.$api_params;
        $url = $smsgatewaydata;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);        
        if(!$output){
           $output =  file_get_contents($smsgatewaydata);
        }

        if($return == '1'){
            return $output;            
        }else{
            echo "Sent";
        }        
    }

/*     * End sendsms_helper.php file     */
```

**How to use:**

- Load sendsms helper as $this->load->helper('sendsms_helper');
- Call sendsms function Ex. sendsms( '919918xxxxxx', 'test message from spring edge' );

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter always keep extra classes in `application/libraries` folder.Then just load these classes where you want as below:

```
$this->load->library(libaray_name);
```

**In your case:**
Save your file in `application/libraries` as `Textlocal.php`.Then load in controller like:

```
$this->load->library('textlocal');
```

Then call the library functions like `$this->textlocal->method_name();`

```
    $numbers = array(MOBILE NUMBER);
    $sender = 'Testing';
    $message = "Your Download image link is available now";
    $this->textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
```